# Yeoman just quits when trying to use bootstrap generator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I haven't used Yeoman very little in the past, but I don't remember havingn this problem. I want to run the bootstrap generator to start working on a new web:

[image]

**It just quits** on my face. The folder remains empty and no errors.
I've tried selecting less or sass just to try, same result. I've uninstalled the whole npm/node thing and reinstalled again. Reinstalled the generator back. Same result.

I'm not finding anything on the internet, so it must be something really stupid on my site. What is it?

Comment: Maybe view this thread could help a little bit?
https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/63

Comment: Excuse me but I don't see how that can help. But i'll post an issue there, thanks.